# My Raspberry Pi 4 does not output sound with my Acer Monitor

Tags: audio, pi-4

I have read every article I can find including the Raspberry Pi foundation website and tried everything that has been suggested but my Raspberry Pi 4 has no sound.

Comment: If you have tried everything, what can we do that you haven't done already? Have you tried a pair of headphones? How are the Pi and monitor connected? What have you tried specifically? Do not add your answers as comments, rather edit your question and add them there.

Comment: Are you running Raspberry Pi o/s or another op sys? Are you running a GUI or command line?  What are you trying to play and via what program?

Answer (score 1):

Does you monitor actually have speakers? I have a number of Acer monitors; of those one has an HDMI input but no speakers and there is no volume control in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to choose HDMI in the Volume control.

If you have a built-in speaker in your Acer Monitor and no sound ... try to use the
raspi-config program in the terminal.

Select the "Advanced Options" and "Audio"

Choose the Audio output: HDMI 1